# Getting a number from an entry text

Tags: c, gtk

I am making an interface using GTK and C. I've put an entry text in my interface, the user will type only numbers. And I need to get the entered numbers to use them later. However, using the function `gtk_entry_get_text` will stock the entered text in a `const` `gchar` variable. How can I get what the user typed as a number?

The code to get the text is:

```
static void ok_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GtkWidget *entry){ 
const gchar *get_text; 
get_text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry)); 
printf("entry contents: %s\n",get_text); }
```

Comment: the code to get the text is:
static void ok_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GtkWidget *entry){
    
    const gchar *get_text;
    get_text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));
    printf("entry contents: %s\n",get_text);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `guint64 g_ascii_strtoll (const gchar *nptr,gchar **endptr,guint base);`
which converts a string to a gint64 value. This function behaves like the standard strtoll() function does in the C locale. For double you could use

```
gdouble g_ascii_strtod (const gchar *nptr, gchar **endptr); I hope this helps.
```